# How do you reference a line in another file using Code Collaborator?

Tags: agile, code-collaborator

In the chat box of file foo.cc I would like to reference a specific line in file bar.cc.

For example, I have `bar.cc:line 12` written in my code collab chat box

In this case, code-collab only recognizes and allows the jump to `bar.cc`, but not to the line. Is it possible to write a reference to line 12 in bar.cc so that when the designer clicks on it in the chat box, they are immediately jumped to that line in the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading, using Code collaborator 7 and talking to our server support admins, there is no support for this functionality.

If you would like to see this type of automatic linking supported in the next version of code-collaborator, then vote on it in the following SmartBear Software support forum post:

https://community.smartbear.com/t5/Collaborator-Feature-Requests/Reference-the-Line-of-Another-File-in-the-Same-Review/idi-p/100236

Comment: Broken line. Was this feature ever addressed?

Comment: I do not believe that the feature was added. However it appears that Smartbear redesigned their forumns. I have created a new feature request there and updated the hyperlink here.

Comment: Broken link* - and thanks for updating! Am I right in thinking you also can't reference a specific defect?

Comment: I am not sure. If Smartbear provides a platform for bug tracking and your company uses that system, then it would make sense for Smartbear to add dynamic linking across their ecosystem. If they didn't then that would be silly. As an example, I know that if you use Atlassian's Jira system for bug tracking and you reference a Jira bug in Atlassian's Stash, then the bug number's hyperlink will be autolinked by their internal plugin.

Answer (score 0):

A simple hack that works on all versions:

Add a comment (or just green tick) on the specified line of the target file.

Then from the "**Review materials**" section, right on the specified line of the target file and copy link address.

Now you have a permalink for the specified line of the target file, which you can paste anywhere (read: any file in any review) for reference.